# How to ask the user for Play Store app review on Wear OS?

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, review

We have developed an app on Wear OS which is linked to our Android app.

However, this Wear OS app can work standalone and Wear OS Play Store user reviews are separate from Android Play Store user reviews.

Therefore, we would like to ask the users of our Wear OS app to review the application on the Play Store? If we understand well, the review must be written from the Play Store on the watch.

Is Google Play In-App Review API (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review) also available and working on Wear OS?

If it is not available, how can we redirect the user from our Wear OS app to the Play Store (and if possible, directly to the section to write a review) to review the Wear OS app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the review api won't work on wear os... wear os google play is very limited. (but test it ;D)

Yes, there are some weird things about review on store ... but in general, i think it is better to review on the phone store, because reviews from watch store will show up only on the watch store, which users dont use much, but anyway...

Two suggestions:

**1 -** You can show a dialog/activity on the wear os app requesting the user to do a review on the watch google play store along with a button that will redirect the user to the watch store. Like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())))
```

or

**2 -** You can show a dialog/activity on the  phone app requesting the user to do a review on the watch google play store along with a button that will open the store on the watch, even if the user does not have the app installed on the watch / or even if the user is using the phone app... I recommend to add a toast after the click with a message, something like "check your watch..."

```
private Node WATCH_NODE;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
     
    new Thread(() -> {
        Task<List<Node>> nodeListTask = Wearable.getNodeClient(getApplicationContext()).getConnectedNodes();

        try {
            WATCH_NODE = Tasks.await(nodeListTask).get(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...
        }
    }).start();

    findViewById(R.id.btn_id).setOnClickListener((l) -> {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);

        i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName()));

        try {
            RemoteActivityHelper remoteActivityHelper = new RemoteActivityHelper(this, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

            remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(i, WATCH_NODE.getId());

            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_check_watch), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Something like this